# Load html and asp server controls via an external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm attempting to dynamically load a table (html & asp server controls) via an external javascript file.  The html controls load with no problem. However the ASP server controls are a no show...  How can I get the server controls to show their face in the place...?

Thanks

external javascript file:

```
function BuildPage() 
{
    var html = "";
    html += "<table width='500px' cellspacing='10'>";
    html += "<tr><td align='center' colspan='2'><h3>Employee Input Form</h3><hr></td></tr>";
    html += "<tr><td>First Name:</td>";
    html += "<td><asp:TextBox ID='tbFName' runat='server'></asp:TextBox></td></tr>";
    html += "<tr><td>Last Name:</td>";
    html += "<td><asp:TextBox ID='tbLName' runat='server'></asp:TextBox></td></tr>";
    html += "<tr><td>Address1:</td>";
    html += "<td><asp:TextBox ID='tbAddr1' runat='server'></asp:TextBox></td></tr>";
    html += "<tr><td>Address2:</td>";
    html += "<td><asp:TextBox ID='tbAddr2' runat='server'></asp:TextBox></td></tr>";
    html += "<tr><td>City:</td>";
    html += "<td><asp:TextBox ID='tbCity' runat='server'></asp:TextBox></td></tr>";
    html += "<tr><td>State:</td>";
    html += "<td><asp:TextBox ID='tbState' runat='server'></asp:TextBox></td></tr>";
    html += "<tr><td>Zip Code:</td>";
    html += "<td><asp:TextBox ID='tbZipCode' runat='server'></asp:TextBox></td></tr>";
    html += "<tr><td>Contry:</td>";
    html += "<td><asp:TextBox ID='tbCountry' runat='server></asp:TextBox></td></tr>";
    html += "<tr><td colspan='2'><asp:Button ID='btnSave' runat='server' Text='Save' /></td>";
    html += "<td><asp:Label ID='lblSaved' runat='server' Text=''></asp:Lavel></td></tr>";
    html += "</table>";
    return html;
}


Default.html:
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <button type='button' onclick="document.write(BuildPage())">Click for Employee Form</button>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a

```
 <asp:TextBox ID='tbZipCode' runat='server'></asp:TextBox>
```

in your ASP.NET Markup, it means that the .NET framework will register this control in the server side, but this doesn't exist in HTML.

.NET Framework will render this control as:

```
<input type="text" ID="tbZipCode" />
```

For example, the "Text" property of your TextBox will be rendered as the "value" attribute of the HTML input control.

So, you can't create your server-side controls with Javascript, since the .NET Framework will not register them, and it'll not render them as well.